# Keyboard PT-PT layout with strange characters

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've been trying to fix the keyboard of Ubuntu 22.04 PT-PT, and I'm finding it quite challenging.

Layout currently with ISO105 PT-PT in Ubuntu:

[image: The current layout]

What it's supposed to be:

[image: What it supose to be]

Is there anything that I can do to reprogram the keyboard layout?
Or does that require some special skill? I'm trying to program and the quotes or the tilde, for example don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols you marked are so called "dead keys" when the standard *Portuguese* keyboard layout is in use. That's useful when typing various accented characters.

To type some of those characters standalone you can press it twice or press it once followed by the space bar.

One option which may be suitable for coding is to switch to the *Portuguese (no dead keys)* layout. That may be better for coding, but less convenient for typing accented characters.